# How to open a pictute displayed from the DB in a new window?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page that shows a couple of pictures. Each image path is stored in the database, and that is the way I am displaying them (from their path) using php.

How can I make it so that when the user clicks on a picture it will be opened in a new window, or a pop up?
I looked at a lot of things, but nothing showed how to do it for output taken from the database. 
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />



<title>VisitBulgaria</title>
</head>



<div class="banner">




<a href="home.html">
<img src="images/banner.png"   alt="home" border="0" height="150" width="500" /></a>

<div class="namelog">


<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION['ID'])){


 echo $Forename." ".$LastName; 
 echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a> &sol; '; 
 echo '<a href="userpage.html">Account</a>'; 

}

 else {

 if (!isset($_SESSION['ID'])){


 echo '<a href="login.php">Log In</a> &sol; ';
 echo '<a href="register.php">Register</a>';

 }
}
?>
</div>



<div class="center11">


<div class="attractions2">


<?php 


if (!$link = mysql_connect()) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('visitbulgaria', $link)) {
    echo 'Could not select database';
    exit;
}


$villageId = $_GET['village']; 
$sql    = "SELECT `AttractionID`, `Name`, `Location`, `Description`, `Airport`, `imglink`,`imglink2`,`imglink3`,`imglink4`,`imglink5`  FROM `attractions` WHERE `AttractionID`='$villageId'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $row['Name']; 
    echo "<br />" ;

    echo " Location: ".$row['Location'] ." ";
    echo "<br />" ;
    echo $row['Description'];
    echo "<br />" ;

    echo " Nearest Airport: ".$row['Airport'] ." ";
    echo "<br />" ;

    echo "<br />";

    echo '<img src="'.$row['imglink'].' " height="200" width="500">';
    echo "<br />";
    echo '<img src="'.$row['imglink2'].' " height="250" width="250">';
    echo "&nbsp";
    echo '<img src="'.$row['imglink3'].' " height="250" width="250">';
    echo "<br />";
    echo '<img src="'.$row['imglink4'].' " height="250" width="250">';
    echo "&nbsp";
    echo '<img src="'.$row['imglink5'].' " height="250" width="250">';




echo "<a href='favourite.php?village=" . $row['AttractionID'] . "  '>" . 

 "<img src='img/fav.png'  > 


       </a>";


}





mysql_free_result($result);



 ?>



 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to paste your entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Add target="_blank" to each img href e.g.

```
 echo '<a href="'.$row['imglink'].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$row['imglink'].' " height="200" width="500"></a>';
```

Comment: I tought it would be something as simple as this! Thank you so much!